# Detect a new tweet with any framework or language (desktop or web-based)

Tags: database, web-applications, twitter

I hope this doesn't get perceived as ambiguous or too vague, but I'm attempting to make a service that monitors Twitter and archives tweets. Apart from PHP cron jobs I can't think of any way to detect if there has been a new tweet posted?

I'm not too fussed about what programming language I have to write it in, or what framework I have to work in. Also whether its desktop or web based.

What route would everyone go down for this?

Comment: Twitter rate limits requests, so if your requirement is true real-time you may be out of luck: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting. As for a client, I'd choose Python and use its threading libraries because it's an easy to work with language and good bindings for desktop GUI libraries.